# Проблема текста

Tags: литература

Помогите, пожалуйста определить проблему следующего текста (мой вариант дан внизу, после текста).

---

> Пьесы Чехова не обнаруживают сразу
> своей поэтической значимости. Прочтя
> их, говоришь себе: "Хорошо, но...
> ничего особенного, ничего
> ошеломляющего. Всё как надо.
> Знакомо... правдиво... не ново."
> Нередко первое знакомство с его
> произведениями разочаровывает.
> Кажется, что нечего рассказывать о них
> по прочтении. Фабула, сюжет?.. Их
> можно изложить в двух словах. Роли?
> Много хороших, но нет выигрышных, за
> которыми погонится актёр на амплуа
> хороших ролей (есть и такой).
> Большинство из них маленькие роли,
> "без ниточки" (т.е. в один лист, не
> требующий ниток для сшивания).
> Вспоминаются отдельные слова пьесы,
> сцены. Но странно: чем больше даёшь
> волю памяти, тем больше хочется думать
> о пьесе. Одни места её заставляют, по
> внутренней связи, вспоминать о других,
> ещё лучших местах и наконец о всём
> произведении. Ещё и ещё перечитываешь
> его - и чувствуешь внутри глубокие
> залежи.   Мне пришлось играть в пьесах
> Чехова одну роль по несколько сот раз,
> но я не помню спектакля, во время
> которого не вскрылись бы в моей душе
> новые ощущения, а в самом произведении
> - новые глубины или тонкости, которые не были мною раньше замечены. Чехов -
> неисчерпаем, потому что, несмотря на
> обыденщину, которую он будто бы всегда
> изображает, он говорит всегда, в своём
> основном духовном лейтмотиве, не о
> случайном, не о частном, а о
> Человеческом с большой буквы. Вот
> почему и мечта его о будущей жизни на
> земле - не маленькая, не мещанская, не
> узкая, а напротив - широкая, большая,
> идеальная, которая, вероятно, так и
> останется несбыточной, к которой надо
> стремиться, но осуществления которой
> нельзя достигнуть.   Чеховские мечты о
> будущей жизни говорят о высокой
> культуре духа, о Мировой Душе, о том
> Человеке, которому нужны не "три
> аршина земли", а весь земной шар, о
> новой прекрасной жизни, для создания
> которой нам надо ещё двести, триста,
> тысячу лет работать, трудиться,
> страдать. Всё это из области вечного,
> к которому нельзя относиться без
> волнения.

---

Текст - отрывок из книги К.С. Станиславского "Моя жизни в искусстве".
Я выделил такие проблемы:
-проблема творчества Антона Павловича.
-проблема гениальности в искусстве.
-проблема достижения идеала/идеального общества.

Предложите свой вариант или исправьте меня, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

"Чехов - неисчерпаем, потому что, несмотря на обыденщину, которую он будто бы всегда изображает, он говорит всегда, в своём основном духовном лейтмотиве, не о случайном, не о частном, а о Человеческом с большой буквы." Лучше Станиславского не скажешь.

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить:
-Проблема понимания пьес Чехова
-Проблема Мировой Души в искусстве

Answer (score 0):

- проблема внешней простоты и внутренней глубины творчества Чехова.
- проблема магнетизма творчества Чехова